# Python logger produces output without handlers

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Every now and then, while running under Jupyter and after interrupting the kernel, I start getting duplicate output on my logger: `stdout.info("foo")` prints:

```
2023-09-19 13:19:19 INFO 17892/MainThread/324310998 foo
INFO:stdout:foo
```

I still have just one handler in the `stdout` logger: `stdout.handlers` is

```
[<StreamHandler stdout (INFO)>]
```

Moreover, if I remove this handler, I still get output:

```
In [96]:
ha = stdout.handlers[0]
stdout.removeHandler(ha)

In [97]:
stdout.handlers
Out [97]:
[]

In [98]:
stdout.info("foo")

INFO:stdout:foo
```

A basic investigation shows that

```
In [99]:
stdout.propagate
Out [99]:
True

In [100]:
stdout.hasHandlers()
Out [100]:
True
```

and `stdout.propagate = False` "fixes" the problem.

Alternatively,

```
root = logging.getLogger()
root.removeHandler(root.handlers[0])
```

also fixes the problem.

However, I would rather figure out how come the root logger all of a sudden got a handler!

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't inadvertently added in your code, something probably called `logging.basicConfig()`, which adds e.g. a `StreamHandler` to the root logger. Hard to tell where because you haven't posted your code, but it could be some third-party library you're using, or something in Jupyter that's doing it.